# How to check if aws functions are supported by localstack?

Tags: lambda, localstack

I am using localstack to fake aws lambda (and many other aws resources), how to check if a particular functionality is supported by localstack or not?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for us, seems that the `Lambda layers` is only available for the premium user as pointed in the following page: https://localstack.cloud/#pricing